# HTML title attribute aligment on RTL sites

Tags: html, title, right-to-left

On chrome/safari browsers html title attribute gets aligned incorrectly.
It works correctly on firefox.

This is how it looks on firefox (OK): http://postimg.org/image/dbniihkv5/
This is how it looks on chrome (FAIL): http://postimg.org/image/c4h8x78nt/

Code of this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
    <img
        title="نور روشن است که در پشت موضوع شما و سنسور جلو و عقب از دست رفته است، آن را برای دوربین اول معلوم شد که."
        width="200"
        height="100"
        src="https://www.imagecomics.com/uploads/banners/images/zero_2_large.jpg">
</body>
```

Any ideas how to get it aligned properly ?

Thank you.

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 3):

I’m afraid you can’t change the alignment, as it is under the control of the browser and immune to CSS settings (except perhaps via some browser-specific hacks). Cf. to [Setting a different direction for the input tag and its title attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692914/setting-a-different-direction-for-the-input-tag-and-its-title-attribute).

The best workaround (well, probably better than a solution would be) is to a CSS (or CSS+JavaScript) tooltip instead of the `title` attribute. You get many extras with this, like the possibility of setting the font face, size, etc. And alignment is automatically correct. Example (with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/PsKw4/1/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
    .tipped { position: relative; }
    .tipped .tip { display: none; position: absolute; right: 1em; top: -3em;}
    .tipped:hover .tip {
      display: block;
      background: #ffe;
      color: black;
      border: solid 1px #333;
      padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
      width: 22em;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<span class=tipped>
<img
        width="200"
        height="100"
        src="https://www.imagecomics.com/uploads/banners/images/zero_2_large.jpg">
<span class=tip>
نور روشن است که در پشت موضوع شما و سنسور جلو و عقب از دست رفته است، آن را برای دوربین اول معلوم شد که.
</span>
</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to making it actually working on my example :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML title is not displayed in HTML frame view in most browsers. Instead, it is displayed in the browser window title bar or tab labels. So Not all of the browsers have implemented direction & alignment for title. They just follow OS language default alignment. (Even the BiDi direction is correct, the alignment follow system default)

In other word, HTML Title could not be controlled with HTML BiDi Attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not all that familiar with the RTL attribute, but I've never seen it in the body tag before, put it in the html tag and try that.

```
<HTML DIR="RTL">
```

Don't forget your page title.  :)

Comment: Problem remains if a put dir="rtl" to a <html> tag. Title is not needed in this page, because this page is just for isolating the problem :)

Comment: And just for a record, you can use dir attribute on any element, not just for body or html tags.